# react: how to get data from redux store in a rendered component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

In my redux store, I have products and cartItems. when I render every single product I also give a button called addToCart on every product. so when I clicked the button, that item is added on the cartItems array (store)

now every cart item has a quantity property. so that if add to cart button is called again, I increment the quantity.

what I want is the value of the quantity of that cartItem in my rendered product component. so that I can conditionally give the add to cart button's text content like that:

`${cartItem.quantity} on bag`

this is my product component:

```
const Product = ({
  id,
  title,
  brand,
  price,
  image_url,
  addCartItem
}) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleAddToCart = (id) => {
    setIsClicked(true);
    addCartItem(id);
  };


  return (
    <div className='product'>
      {/* <Link to={`/product/${id}`}> */}
      <img src={image_url} alt={title} />
      <div className='title'>
        <span>{title}</span>
        <span>{brand}</span>
      </div>
      {/* </Link> */}
      <div className='actions'>
        <span>${price}</span>
        <button onClick={() => handleAddToCart(id)}>
          {isClicked ? `${I need quantity here} in Bag` : 'Add to Cart'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you have a reducer named `cartItems[]` and in which you store `product{}` after user clicks add to cart button. Okay, simple logic. Now what you want is a property named `quantity` that is in every product of `cartItems[]`. You can get that property using redux's `useSelector` hook(since you're using hooks).

```
const { quantity } = useSelector(store => store.cartItems.find(item => item.id === id));
```

What we are doing here is that we are getting the target product from the cartItems array
using the `id` that's getting passed in as argument and then accessing the quantity from that product. This will be very bad for performance if the products[] list is large and the cartItems[] is large as well. Try to use an object to store the cartItems{} and access it like

```
const quantity = useSelector(store => store.cartItems[id].quantity);
```

This approach is very performant since there's no loop, it's O(1).

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you connected properly the reducer to the global store using combinereducer,  if you connected then you can use like this -
import the **useSelector** from the react-redux, since you are using react hooks,

```
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';
```

and simply call useSelector inside the function like this to get the data

```
  const taskDetails = useSelector((state) => (state.taskDetails.entities));
```